# Split the string every special character with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, split

I want to split my string into pieces but *every some text **and** a special character*. I have a string:
`str = "ImEmRe@b'aEmRe@b'testEmRe@b'string"`
I want my string to be split every `EmRe@b'` characters as you can see it contais the `'` and that's the problem.
I tried doing `re.split(r"EmRe@b'\B", str)`, `re.split(r"EmRe@b?='\B", str)` and also I tried both of them but without the `r` before the pattern. How do I do it? I'm really new to regular expressions. I would even say I've never used them.

Comment: Do you want to make sure there is a word char  after `'`? Then just use `re.split(r"EmRe@b'\b", text)`

Comment: It's not a duplicate. As you can see, I've chosen the best answer and if you don't know what I meant in the question then look at the answer and you will realize that It's not a duplicate :).

Comment: This is duplicate because you need to remove `\B` and your pattern would work. All you need to know is what `\B` is, and that is what the linked post is about.

Comment: Removing `\B` didn't work. The marked answer worked.

Comment: [Can't find any difference in output](https://ideone.com/Qfgrit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, change the name of your variable, since `str()` is a built-in Python function.
If you named your variable `word`, you could get a list of elements split by your specified string by doing this:

```
>>> word = "ImEmRe@b'aEmRe@b'testEmRe@b'string"
>>> word
"ImEmRe@b'aEmRe@b'testEmRe@b'string"
>>> word.split("EmRe@b'")
['Im', 'a', 'test', 'string']
```

Allowing you to use them in many more ways than just a string! It can be saved to a variable, of course:

```
>>> foo = word.split("EmRe@b'")
>>> foo
['Im', 'a', 'test', 'string']
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. Why it does not work with regular expressions though?

Comment: Wouldn't know... I don't use it as much since raw Python does it for me faster and easier...